# Browsers Keep popping phishing websites (I think)

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave

I have a 2017 MBP, Recently a friend of mine installed Logic Pro X via a torrent. But recently I see a lot of pop up similar to websites I visit. e.g If I am nike website, it open a new tab and in milliseconds changes the url and land on nike, same for other websites as well.

I tried disabling kaspersky extension for safari but didn't help.

I tried stopping MacPerfomance but it didn't stop. How can I get rid of it?

Comment: You can try running Malwarebytes Anti-Malware to see if it picks up a rootkit or other malware.  https://www.malwarebytes.com/mac/

Answer (score -3):

Macperfomance is malware advertising mackeeper, so first of all keep yourself out of this soft, never install mackeeper.

In order to clean this shit your should first delete file mackeeper.plist and all other files you can't recognize as your desired software from folders /library/LaunchAgents,  /library/LaunchDaemons,  /users/*%yourusername%*/library/LaunchAgents

After that close all your apps and reboot your Mac

Comment: How does this answer the question asked? Also, deleting files from these folders can have a negative impact on your system if you don‘t know what you are doing.